# How to add extra parameters to html tag from base django

Tags: python, html, angularjs, django

lets say i have a html tag as follows in my base.html.

```
<html lang="en-us" "some other properties">
```

i have another template with head as:

```
 <html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">
```

I am extending the base template to the new template i want in that extended template head to be as

```
  <html lang="en" data-ng-app="app" "some other properties">
```

how can i achive the same in django using block statements?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I usually have one AngularJS app per Django site and multiple controllers used inside the child templates.

Comment: Why does the extended template need the html tag?

Comment: You just put a block statement there? What is the problem? Why can't you achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1):

In base.html

```
<html lang="en-us" {% block np_app %}{% endblock %}  "some other properties">
```

In other.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block np_app %} data-ng-app="app" {% endblock %}
```